# How to render different images based on screen size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to render a different svg based on the browser screen width. I've found a solution that expects me to use `srcSet` within an img tag. However, I can't get it to work.

The goal should be to render `SmallTalents` on mobile, and `BigTalents` on tablets+

Quick notes:

- I'm using TailwindCSS.
- The svgs are completely different, not just scaled down versions.

### Example

```js
import React from "react";
import SmallTalents from "../../../assets/smallTalents.svg";
import BigTalents from "../../../assets/bigTalents.svg";

function Example() {
  return (
    <section>
      <img
        srcSet={`${SmallTalents}, 200w ${BigTalents} 600w`}
        sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px, 800px"
        src={SmallTalents}
        alt="talents"
      />
    </section>
  );
}

export default Example;
```

### Update:

Tried this, not working

```js
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 300px)" srcset={SmallTalents} />
  <source media="(min-width: 900px)" srcset={BigTalents} />
</picture>
```

### Solution (not ideal)

```js
<img src={SmallTalents} alt="talents" className="my-5 md:hidden" />
<img src={BigTalents} alt="talents" className="my-5 hidden md:flex" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use picture element in html for rendering different images based on the screen size:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_food.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_car.jpg">
  <img src="img_girl.jpg">
</picture>
```

Comment: I've updated my post. Doesn't seem to be working. Added closing tags because was getting an error, and removed the img tag because it was double rendering.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-lederberg-dcdkce?file=/src/App.js   .As you can see here in the the link. It's working fine add the img tag also.

Comment: Viewed that, and it's not working on my end. Shows an error with the `source` closing tags. If I close them, the image will not render.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small typo in your srcSet property, the 200w should be on the left side of the comma. i.e `srcSet={`${SmallTalents} 200w, ${BigTalents} 600w`}`

Comment: Gave that a shot, but it's still not changing the svg on screen sizes

Comment: Have you cleared the cache (CTRL + SHIFT+R) while having the browser window resized (not toggled in dev tools mobile / tablet ) to be smaller / bigger than the srcSet sizes? Once the browser has the higher resolution picture (loaded in cache) there is no point for it to download the lower quality one, even when you make your window smaller, to save traffic.

Comment: The images are completely different. Not just scaled down versions.